# Точки пересечения двух отрезков

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Как найти координаты точки пересечения двух отрезков за координатами их начал и концов?(C/C++). Например, пользователь вводит:

- ax1, ay1, ax2, ay2 - координаты начала и конца первой прямой;
- bx1, by1, bx2, by2 - координаты начала и конца второй прямой;
- cx, cy - координаты некой точки с которой мы будем сравнивать найденное пересечение;

То есть вводятся координаты двух отрезков и точки, нужно узнать - является ли точка пересечением данных отрезков?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, надеюсь, помним, что прямая линия описывается линейной функцией y=ax+b.

Имея координаты 2 точек, принадлежащих этой прямой, x1,y1 x2,y2. можно посчитать значения a и b

a = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

b = y1 - x1*a

Получив эти коэффициенты для 2 прямых, проверяем

```
if ((a1*cx +b1) == cy && (a2*cx+ b2) == cy) puts ("Принадлежит");
```

Comment: Ингвар(Ingvarr или Inglar) - скандинавское имя. Ингвар — бог плодородия. У разных народов имени Игорь соответствуют имена: Igor → Gor → Iggor, Ingvar, Inglar, Ingmar, Ingemar, Yngwie, Yngvi, Yngve, Yngvin, Ingwine, Inguin, Ігор и др.
Источник - Ваши и наши интернеты.

Comment: Я про ник, а не про имя. Имя - это слишком просто.

Comment: Большая борода?

Comment: На каком языке?

Comment: Исландский

Comment: Точнее - на древнеисландском. Получите плюсик.

Comment: Большая борода